# Pyspark: how to set SparkContext by running only the master?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am quite new to `spark` and `pyspark`

I am working on a cluster with a master and 2 workers.

I would like to setup the `SparkContext` that work only with the master since the 2 workers are not availble.

Howe can I setup it? This is what I am doing.

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/usr/lib/spark/')
import pyspark 
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

but I get an error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set master to local instead of using Spark, Mesos or Yarn url. Set master to local to run with one thread or local[N] with N number of threads. e.g. when set master to local[2] it will create two threads to process data on local.

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[2]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

And about error, it's different issue. Seems like your name node is running safe mode. That's why you are seeing the error. Get your name node to normal.